# Understanding chain probability notation?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm going over [markov models](http://dingo.sbs.arizona.edu/~hammond/ling178-sp06/mathCh8.pdf) and I'm tying to understand the following notation for chain probability:

$$p(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) = p(a_1)p(a_2\mid a_1)p(a_3\mid a_1,a_2)p(a_4\mid a_1,a_2,a_3)$$

> "The Chain Rule is one simple consequence of the definition of conditional probability: the joint probability of some set of events $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$ can also be expressed as a ‘chain’ of conditional probabilities"

Can someone explain?

Comment: Unrelated to the Markov property, always true, simply iterates Bayes formula $$p(a,b)=p(a)p(b\mid a)$$ for various $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of conditional probability, we have $P(A,B) = P(A\mid B)P(B)$, where $P(A,B)$ means $P(A\cap B)$.

Now taking $A=a_4$ and $B = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$, we get:
$$P(a_4,a_3,a_2,a_1) = P(a_4\mid a_1, a_2, a_3)P(a_1,a_2,a_3)$$
Now with $A = a_3$ and $B=(a_1,a_2)$ the last factor can be written
$$P(a_1,a_2,a_3) = P(a_3\mid a_1,a_2)P(a_1,a_2)$$
Once again, $P(a_1,a_2)$ is $P(a2\mid a_1)P(a_1)$ and you get your formula.